# Android HTTPS webservice XmlPullParserException

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I'm  using  HttpsTransportSE call to connect our webservice.

We have added firewall to our server which converts http to https

This is actual soap message without firewall. (It has normal http)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

It is the one with firewall.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

As you can see, the http is converted to https.

So http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/  was changed to https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

So that i am getting XmlPullParserException

```
12-29 00:20:48.214: E/XmlPullParserException(5367): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault (position:START_TAG <{https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soap:Fault>@1:234 in java.io.InputStreamReader@417bc9a8)
```

How can i fix this issue?

How can i change it to https?

I have tried this.

```
envelope.env="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
```

But it didn't work.

Please help.